# Angular view not updated on new observable data

Tags: angular

I have a angular component 
with a constructor like this:

```
    newTrips$: Observable<Trip[]>;
    constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>, private tripFeedService: TripFeedService) {
       this.newTrips$ = store.select(fromRoot.getTripFeedUnreadTrips);
       this.newTrips$.subscribe(x => { console.log('subscribe'); console.log(x); });
    }
```

In the view I have this:

```
<div *ngFor="let trip of newTrips$ | async">test</div>
```

The problem is that if the Trip[] is empty if the page is loaded. the ngfor in the view wil never be called. My console does display the log messages displaying 'subscribe' and the objects in a list. If you refresh the page the items are displayed and all following changes of the observable are properly displayed in the console and ui

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `async` in the `ngFor`, no need to subscribe to the observable inside the constructor.

```
newTrips$: Observable<Trip[]>;
    constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>, private tripFeedService: TripFeedService) {
       this.newTrips$ = store.select(fromRoot.getTripFeedUnreadTrips);
    }
```

Comment: the subscription in the construction is just for logging.

Comment: It's better to use .do() for side effects like logging. If the Observable is not multicast/hot you create two subscriptions this can cause unwanted side effects.